# In msys2, Cd to directory I have full permissions to fails with "permission denied"

Tags: file-permissions, msys2

I'm used to Cygwin, but experimenting with Msys2.  I did a default 64-bit install (on Windows 10), and things seemed to work, until I started trying to use it.  Today for example I've encountered this: I get "permission denied" when I attempt to CD to a directory I have full permissions to (ls -l shows me having full permissions, but in addition to that I checked using Windows File Explorer and it shows user ddb having full control of this directory).

I see that Msys2 has mounted c: noacl; that's a default, nobody asked me, but it *ought* to be a good thing for simplifying this kind of issue.

`$ ls -al
total 13k
drwxr-xr-x 1 ddb Users 0 Sep 15 16:04 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 ddb Users 0 Sep 15 23:32 ..
drwxr-xr-x 1 ddb Users 0 Sep 16 13:08 cygwin
drwxr-xr-x 1 ddb Users 0 Sep 15 14:07 freebsd
drwxr-xr-x 1 ddb Users 0 Sep 15 14:04 linux
drwxr-xr-x 1 ddb Users 0 Sep 16 13:16 msys
drwxr-xr-x 1 ddb Users 0 Sep 15 14:04 solaris
$ id
uid=197611(ddb) gid=545(Users) groups=545(Users),197121(None),4(INTERACTIVE),66049(CONSOLE LOGON),11(Authenticated Users),15(This Organization),113(Local account),4095(CurrentSession),66048(LOCAL),262154(NTLM Authentication),401408(Medium Mandatory Level)
ddb@ddblap7:~/Documents/IxSetup/ostypes
$ cd msys
bash: cd: msys: Permission denied`

Comment: More details: this Windows 10 system is *not* joined to a domain.